# Cant get python to properly work on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

this is the error I'm getting

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 's'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd 'c:\Users\Sean's awesome\Documents\Python Projects\Test Prject'; $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: The problem should be clearly visible by looking at VS Code's syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the apostrophe in `Sean's awesome` is causing that error

The apostrophe is ending the location string here `'c:\Users\Sean'`

Remove this from your user and try again.